# Обёртка в -col- лишняя?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Насколько корректно в bootstrap навешивать классы `-col-` на таблицу?

То есть вместо:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <table class="table">
        ...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Сразу писать без обёртки в `row` и `-col-`:

```
<table class="table col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        ...
</table>
```

Вроде бы в последних FF и Chrome работает как надо, но интересно вообще насколько корректно навешивать флексы (на них я так понимаю сделаны col в четвертом бутстрапе) на таблицу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Философский вопрос, так как можно сделать всё что угодно, и оно даже может работать. Но на мой взгляд это совершенно не корректно. `col` и `row` отвечают за сетку, и их не следует путать с другими элементами без надобности. Корректно было бы положить таблицу во внутрь `col`, ну или в ячейку положить `row` вместе c `col`. Сами бутстрап [пишут](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/), что весь контент должен оборачиваться в эти элементы, допустима любая вложенность. Не хочешь отступов - вешай [no-gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#no-gutters).

Если их совместить то как минимум, таблица вылезет за контент. Наглядный пример:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Контент</h1>
        <p class="lead">Контент, какой-то там контент...</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Таблица внутри col</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>5</th>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                    row>col внутри ячейки
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
                    1
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    2
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    3
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-dark col-12">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="4">Таблица + col</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>5</th>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>9</th>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```